# Where is the history of the 'run' dialogue saved on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I want to write a script which cleans the 'run' dialogue automatically every log off. Where is the history stored?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From:

[How to Remove Individual Entries from Run Command History](http://www.pchell.com/support/editrunmrulistentries.shtml)

> Where is the Run MRU (Most Recently
>   Used) List?
>
> The RUNMRU list is stored in the
>   Windows Registry in the following
>   location:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ Software\
>   Microsoft\ Windows\ CurrentVersion\
>   Explorer\ RunMRU\
>
> Is There a Program to Delete
>   Individual Entries from the RUNMRU
>   List?
>
> Many of my customers would rather not
>   edit the Windows registry to remove
>   these individual entries, so I setup a
>   VBScript that you can download and run
>   to delete individual commands from
>   this list. Follow these instructions
>   to download and use this program to
>   clear unwanted entries from the Run
>   Command history.
>
> 1) Click on the following link and
>   download the EditRunMRUList.vbs script
>   to your desktop
>
> Download [EditRunMRUList.vbs](http://www.pchell.com/downloads/editrunmrulist.vbs)

Answer (score 3):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use registry, just use Win32 SH api to clean it.